# The integers in the array are either entirely odd or entirely even except for a single integer. Retrieve this single integer. JS

Tags: javascript, integer

You are given an array (which will have a length of at least 3, but could be very large) containing integers. The integers in the array are either entirely odd or entirely even except for a single integer N. Write a method that takes the array as an argument and returns N.

For example:
[2, 4, 0, 100, 4, 11, 2602, 36]
Should return: 11

My test cases that need to work:

```
Test.assertEquals(findOutlier([0, 1, 2]), 1)
Test.assertEquals(findOutlier([1, 2, 3]), 2)
Test.assertEquals(findOutlier([2,6,8,10,3]), 3)
Test.assertEquals(findOutlier([0,0,3,0,0]), 3)
Test.assertEquals(findOutlier([1,1,0,1,1]), 0)
```

My code so far, that doesn't seem to work:

```
function findOutlier(integers){
    var evens = [];
    var odds = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < integers.length; i++) {
        if (integers[i] % 2) {
            evens.push(integers[i]);
        } else {
            odds.push(integers[i]);
        }
    }
    var elen = evens.length;
    var olen = odds.length

    if (elen > olen) {
        return odds;
    } else {
        return evens;
    }
}
```

What do I need to change with this code please?

Comment: You should return the single outlier, not the array of outliers. Also, `integers[i] % 2` should be compared to 0.

Comment: @MichaelLiu Thanks, isn't that what I am doing? There will only be one odd or even number so that would be the only one being returned? Thank-you!

Comment: The variables `odds` and `evens` are **arrays** and you're returning the whole thing. Should be `return odds[0]` or `return evens[0]` instead.

Comment: @Pointy, thanks I've changed that but don't seem to be getting a result?

Comment: Are there errors in the console?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45664127/7879193

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see 2 possible modification : 
1) Return the single value in your array and not all the array

```
return evens[0];
```

Change your if to check if the modulo == 0 ( if the remainder = 0 it is an even number)

```
if ((integers[i] % 2) == 0)
```

-

```
function findOutlier(integers){
   var evens = [];
   var odds = [];
   for (var i = 0; i < integers.length; i++) 
   {
       if ((integers[i] % 2) == 0) 
       {
           evens.push(integers[i]);
       } 
       else 
       {
           odds.push(integers[i]);
       }
   }
   var elen = evens.length;
   var olen = odds.length;

   if (elen > olen)
   {
       return odds[0];
   } 
   else 
   {
       return evens[0];
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank-you that works. Could I ask what this bit does please? `((integers[i] % 2) == 0) ` ?

Comment: The modulo will return the remainder after the division by 2 so if it is an even number the remainder will be zero and if it is an odd number the remainder will be 1 ![ONLINE EXAMPLE OF MODULO](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/cryptography/modarithmetic/a/what-is-modular-arithmetic)

Answer (score 2):

First, your condition should be:

```
if (integers[i] % 2 === 0) {
```

and you need to return the first element of the array:

```
return odds[0];
```

Here's how I might approach it:

```js
function findOutlier(arr) {

  const result = arr.reduce(function(p, c) {
    p[c % 2 === 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'].push(c);
    return p;
  }, { odd: [], even: []});

  const eLen = result.even.length;
  const oLen = result.odd.length;
  
  if (oLen < eLen) {
    return oLen > 1 ? result.odd : result.odd[0];
  } else {
    return eLen > 1 ? result.even : result.even[0];
  };

}

console.log(findOutlier([2, 4, 0, 100, 4, 11, 2602, 36]))
```

Comment: Excellent answer, very concise.

Comment: Im wondering are you able to run your code on Jfiddle or it is just to give an example of how to use the function  ?

Answer (score 2):

I had spare time... and I did this, javascript is very funny it could be nice to get another view.

```
var numbers = [2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,17,18,20];

function findOutlier(arr) {
    var odds = arr.filter(function (number) {
    return !!(number % 2)
  });

  var evens = arr.filter(function (number) {
    return !(number % 2)
  });

  var result = (odds.length < evens.length) ? odds.pop() : evens.pop();

  return result;
}

findOutlier(numbers);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an approach that uses O(1) memory. No additional arrays are generated. It checks how many of the first 3 values are even. If that number is 2 or more, it looks for an odd value. Else, it looks for an even value.

```js
function findOutlier(arr) {
  //Big O: memory = 1, time = n;
  
  let evenCount = 0;
  
  for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    let val = arr[i];
    if(val % 2 === 0) evenCount ++;
    
  }
  
  let isEven = evenCount > 1;
  
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if((arr[i] % 2 === 0) !== isEven) return arr[i]; 
//Check to see if number is opposite of even counts boolean
  }
  
  return new Error('Array contains no outlier.');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function findOne(arr){
   let evenOrOdd = {"even": [], "odd": []};

   for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
      let oddCount = evenOrOdd["odd"].length,
          evenCount = evenOrOdd["even"].length;

      if(oddCount===1 && evenCount>1 || evenCount===1 && oddCount>1) {
          break;
      }

      arr[i]%2===1 ?
        evenOrOdd["odd"].push(arr[i]) :
        evenOrdOdd["even"].push(arr[i]);
   });

   return evenOrOdd["odd"].length===1 ? 
            evenOrOdd["odd"][0] :
            evenOrOdd["even"][0];         
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Python version of finding an even or odd number in an array containing multiple even or odd numbers with one being either of them. eg: [2,78,1004,13] = 13, [111,81,79,4,10023] = 4.

```
def find_outlier(integers):
    lst_odd = [] # makin new odd list
    lst_even = [] # making new even list
    for i in integers:
     # checking if these numbers are even or odd.
        if i % 2 == 0 :
             # if even they will be added in this list otherwise only one is added.
            lst_even.append(i) 
        else:
     # if odd, they are added here, otherwise, only one is added
            lst_odd.append(i)

    #checking if whether these two list contains only one element.  if so we return that element.
    if len(lst_odd) == 1:
        return lst_odd[0]
    else:
        return lst_even[0]
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/21436622)

Answer (score 0):

check the first 3 numbers, if two of them are the same, return the outlier:

```
function findOutlier(integers){
  //your code here

  if (integers[0]%2 === 0 && integers[1]%2 === 0 ) {
      return integers.find(integer => integer %2 !== 0)
 } else if(integers[0]%2 !== 0 && integers[1]%2 !== 0) {
      return integers.find(integer => integer % 2 === 0)
 } else {
      if(integers[2]%2 === 0){
          return integers.find(integer => integer %2 !==0)
      }
      else {
          return  integers.find(integer => integer %2 ===0)
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int find(List integers) {
  List odd = [];
  List even = [];
  
  integers.forEach((number) {
    if (number % 2 == 0) even.add(number);
    else odd.add(number);
  });
  
  if (even.length < odd.length) return even[0];
  return odd[0];

}
```

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. Future readers will be grateful to see explained *why* this answers the question instead of having to infer it from the code. Also, since this is an old question, please explain how it complements the other answers.

Answer (score -1):

```
function findOutlier(integers) {
    //your code here
    integers.sort();
    var count = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (integers[i] % 2 === 0) {
            count += 1;
        }
    }
    if (count >= 2) {
        var r = integers.filter(function(x) {
            return x % 2 !== 0;
        });
    } else {
        var r = integers.filter(function(x) {
            return x % 2 === 0;
        });
    }

    return r[0];
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.